# How do I change an object's location on the report layout page?

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt

I am using BIRT in eclipse, I have 3 charts on the page. I can change the size of each one and the order in which they appear, but not the physical location on the page and it's driving me crazy. Everything is snapped to the left side of the page.

Am I missing something obvious? How can I change the physical location of the object?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A grid element is what you need to achieve this. Insert a grid in the report, and then drop your charts within, in order to to take advantage of the "text align" property of grid cells to center charts, left-align, right-align etc.

Have a look at [this example](http://www.visioneo.org/drill-actions): we define a grid with two columns and two rows.

- We dragged one chart into each cell of the first grid-row, and make use of padding & text-align property of cells for a fine setting
- In the second grid-row we merged two cells to be able to center the third chart

[image]

We can also insert a grid into another grid, this is sometimes necessary to get exactly the result we want.

Comment: Thanks. This worked well enough, although it just seems like a really inefficient implementation of customizing layout.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a lot of headaches with this, but then I figured out that BIRT report layout is supposed to be built using tables, grids and things like that in the HTML, but you don't have as many options like when designing HTML page.

Use table to place all your elements and try to play with empty cell's width to position elements on screen.

However, regarding your frustration with everything positioned left, you change the report orientation in *Property Editor - Report* when you can select report root:

[image]